# Replicating web application traffic to another instance for testing

Tags: web-server, web-applications

I have a .net web application, I wanted to test APM solutions like newrelic or appdynamics. Unfortunately I had issues with newrelic. When I installed .net agent of newrelic, every now and then some new exceptions was happening. I guess it was due to deep attachment of nr agent to .net runtime.

Now I want to test appdynamics and I don't want get exception in production. How can I replicate traffic to another instance of my application and test appdynamics, meanwhile protecting production environment from any possible exception?

Comment: something like teeproxy https://github.com/chrislusf/teeproxy

Comment: @Nixphoe
is it probable that a transaction partially executed and causes inconsistency among DB instances and consequently lowering the quality of parallel testing?